# SublimeText(3) plug-in onload event?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to develop some plugin for SublimeText3.

The plugin use a node.js server, and I want it keep running as a single instance(service).

So, what I would design the plugin is

to try TCP connect on the plugin load, and

- if the connection succeeded and received data, do nothing
- if the connection failed, execute the node command to launch the new server instance

However, I cannot find any EventListener for plugin-onload Here

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html

What is the common manner to achieve what I would like to do in SublimeText Plugin??

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a function named plugin_loaded, the code inside will be executed when the plugin is loaded

```
def plugin_loaded():
    # your code here
```

Comment: This method works with sublime text 2 as well? If not, is there any equivalent to use with sublime text 2?